# Selenium Chromedriver C# findelementsbytagname("A")

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I select the third tag `<a>` of web using Selenium ChromeDriver?

That's what I tried, but it's not working.

```
ChromeDriver crome = new ChromeDriver(); 
crome.FindElementsByTagName("a")[3];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved creating a WebElement object in my case

```
IWebElement thing;
```

Then I give it the value.

```
thing=crome.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))[3];
thing.SendKeys("\n");
```

The "\n" it's to press the enter key when you have selected the element.

Answer (score 0):

`FindElementsByTagName` is a `RemoteWebDriver` method. With `ChromeDriver` you need to use

```
crome.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
```

Comment: And how can I select the third tag on Chrome?

Comment: @AritzBello With index, like in your question. It will be index 2 and not 3 though.

Answer (score 0):

try `crome.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(), 'Put Your Text Here')])[2]"));`

You can also instead of text use href or other things that  tag has

Comment: Well, What I want is to select the third <a href="javascript...">  who do refer to a javascript to open a web tool. And I don't know how to do, I never use Selenium :( 

And my english is not so good, sorry for that.